# Creating ArcGIS Signature File fails

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

When I try to create a signature file in ArcMap 10.7.1 I am getting an error.

`error: failed to create signature file`

I tried making a Map copy to `c:\gis`, shapefile copy to `c:\gis`, and tried to save the signature file to `c:\gis` (from `c:\gis\assignment`) that previously was and didn't do any good. The same goes for when I tried to save at the desktop.

[image]

Comment: Try using the GP tool(Create Signatures (Spatial Analyst)), as the sample field will default to an integer or string field if present within the input sample data. This is the field of the input raster or feature sample data to assign values to the sampled locations (classes).
Also, use a short name without spaces for the file.

Only integer or string fields are valid fields. The specified number or string will be used as the Class name in the output signature file which will subsequently group the data.